# Refresh a java variable

Tags: java, variables, refresh

I have an problem: I have an random variable used in an string, but when I apply the string again, it does't updates the variable here is my code:

```
int Low = 56;
int High = 92;
int R = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
```

this sits directly in the class

Comment: Is r an instance of `Random`? And where are you applying a string? Please post all of the relevant code.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, can you provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?

Comment: There are a lot of things that could make your question clearer. First, is `r` an `int`, a `Random`, or some other type? Second, could you give us an example of how you are using your code segment more than once and the code you are using to do so? (By the way, a code segment is NOT a string.) If you give us a more complete question, we can better provide an answer that will be helpful to you and solve your problem effectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a setter method and call that every time you apply the string something like

```
setX(int x){
   this.x = x;}
```

then that would update your variable to whatever the most current is.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int Low = 56;
        int High = 92;
        Random r = new Random();
        int R = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
        System.out.println(R);
        R = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
        System.out.println(R);
```

you will have two different `R`